# Google Assistant App Actions and Conversational Actions

Tags: android, kotlin

for my university internship i have to interface an app with Google Assistant and thought it was possible, correct me if i'm wrong. I've been struggling quite a bit to understand from zero how to do it but i got working the App Action 'START_EXERCISE' so i moved on and started to consider the requirements of this project:

- The conversation with the Assistant has to be in Italian
- I need different Actions from the ones listed here [BIIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents)

The target devices are Android

- Problem n1: The App Actions listed don't support Italian language
  (there's written that they support different locales but it's a joke,
  99% only English. Well not a huge problem, i can create custom App   Actions but this lead to problem n2
- Problem n2: Custom App Actions    are limited to English only [Custom
  BIIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/custom-intents)
  Desperate i continued searching for solutions and found that  Conversational Actions could do the job [Conversational Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational)
- Problem n3: Realizing that Converstational Actions will be shutted   down in June 2023 and it wouldn't make sense to start developing with
  that since this project will be added to an existing app of the company that i'm working for the internship

I really need help, what can i do? Are there any workaround or solutions or this simply cannot be done?